# how to get free space in BOX SDK in iOS?

Tags: xcode, sdk, tableview, box

I am trying to display free space of box.com in my app of iOS. But which function I use for log in user? Any Idea.

-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo *)info
{

double spacecConsumed=info.quota.totalBytes;

double totalSpace=info.quota.totalConsumedBytes;

double freeSpace = (spacecConsumed - totalSpace) ;

appDelegate.dropBoxSize =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ free of  %@", [self transformedValue:freeSpace],[self transformedValue:spacecConsumed]];

CopyScreen *copyScreen =[[CopyScreen alloc] init];
    copyScreen.leftViewC = [[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers firstObject] viewControllers] firstObject];
    [copyScreen.leftViewC.leftTable reloadData]; }

This is for dropbox. I need to same apply for box.com with its own function. How to do that?

Free  Space :

Total Space :